# React-native child component not updating when parent state updates

Tags: react-native

I have a parent component which holds a child component. The parent is getting its data from redux. The object in store looks something like the below:

```
//object in redux store
object :[{
      item: {
         name: 'item'1,
         selected: false
         },
      item:{
         name: 'item'1,
         selected: false
    }
   }]
```

My Parent component contains a FlatList which renders the child component:

```
//parent component
<FlatList
  data={this.props.object}
  renderItem={( object ) => <Object object={object.item} />}
  keyExtractor={object => object.id}
/>
```

My child component contains a button, which toggles the selected property of each item. The desired behavior is that the style of the button changes based on the value if the selected property. My child button component looks something like the below:

```
// child component
render(){
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
       <Button 
         title="toggle"
         buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: this.props.selected? 'red' : 'green'}}
         onPress={() => handling toggle by changing state in store, it works fine and 
         console.logs correctly}/>
    </View>
 );
}
```

After the button is toggled, the state of the object does change, and console.logs correctly, however the style of the button only updated when i go out and back into the page as if the child component is not updating.

How can i get the button style to update directly on button toggle? Thanks

Comment: Could you show me redux.connect part?

Answer (score 0):

More information would help, but my initial thoughts are that the toggled state might not be causing the FlatList component to pick up the changes, in order to trigger a re-render.

This can be resolved by the optional `extraData` prop that can be passed into your FlatList component

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the changes I was doing in my reducer did not trigger a component update due to the shallow equality comparison redux performs.

I fixed by returning this in my reducers

```
let obj = {...}
return { ...state, object: {...state.object}
```

instead of

```
let obj = {...}
return {...state, object: obj }
```